# Mondrian Error:No function matches signature '<String> + <String>'

Tags: mdx, mondrian

Getting above mentioned  error for this mdx query  :

```
With 
member [Measures].[MTD1] as 
Sum({StrToMember('[Year Month Day].[Date].&[' + FORMAT(Now(), 'yyyy') + '-' + FORMAT(Now(),'mm') + '-01' + ']')
: StrToMember('[Year Month Day].[Date].&[' + FORMAT(Now(), 'yyyy') + '-' + FORMAT(Now(),'mm') + FORMAT(Now(),'dd') + ']')}
, [Measures].[Amount])

member [Measures].[MTD2] as
Sum({StrToMember('[Year Month Day].[Date].&[' + FORMAT(Now(), 'yyyy') + '-' + FORMAT(dateadd('mm',-1,now())) + '-01' + ']')
: StrToMember('[Year Month Day].[Date].&[' + FORMAT(Now(), 'yyyy') + '-' + FORMAT(dateadd('mm',-1,now())) + FORMAT(Now(),'dd') + ']')}
, [Measures].[Amount])

member [Measures].[%MTD Growth] as
([Measures].[MTD1]-[Measures].[MTD2])/[Measures].[MTD1], FORMAT_STRING='0.00%'

Select {[Measures].[Amount],[Measures].[MTD1],[Measures].[MTD2],[Measures].[%MTD Growth]} ON COLUMNS,
[Transaction Place].Members ON ROWS
from [TXNSumCube]
```

Date is stored as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: first Google hit for "string concatenation in Mondrian": http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?68319-String-concatenation-in-MDX

Comment: thankz for the reply..error resolved @whytheq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mondrian instead of '+', use '||'.